# why stepper motor lose magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have very old desktop style 3 axis cnc machine. There were 2 dc motors for X-Y axis and a unipolar stepper for Z axis. I replaced the old DC motors with unipolar steppers. I personally made the drivers for X-Y axis , since unipolar motor driver is easy to make using power transistors. Z axis stepper already had its own driver and I continued to use it as it is. I use Arduino Mega to control the motors, lcd, buttons, encoders, etc... The library that I use to drive steppers is Accelstepper library. Everything was very fine and the whole cnc worked very accurately.

Suddenly, both X and Y axis steppers started losing steps first, and then they are totaly failed. Now, they only vibrate and shafts don't turn, at all.

I checked/tested the drivers with an oscilloscope and an am-meter and found that they work as expected. I had more steppers with the same brand/model. I replaced the steppers with new ones for testing the drivers and other staff. Everything is OK! Finally, when I try to turn the shafts by hand, I feel the detent of the new steppers, but the shafts of the failed ones just turn easily like a dc motor without feeling of detent. This situation suggested me that somehow they lost magnetism.

But how? What may be the reason for that? I need to know the reason and solve the issue before I start using the machine with new steppers, since probably they will fail too, because of the same reason...
Thanks.

Comment: "There were 2 dc motors for X-Y axis" switching from servomotors to steppers sounds like a huge step backwards.  Stepper motor magnets can be damaged by excessive current, excessive heat, or in some types simply disassembly.   It's not clear if you made a proper driver; did you implement chopping current control?  Does it actually work properly?

Comment: Too much current can demagnetise a motor. Have you ever over-currented the windings? What is the spec for maximum current for those motors?

Comment: I think you've fried your steppers windings. Rr-check your drive circuit for proper current control.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments.

Comment: The machines I have built 15yrs ago with stepper motors are still running, industrial, 12 hrs per day.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks you for your comments first... They were not servo motors, they were conventional brushed DC motors. I found difficult to use DC motors with encoders for accurate movement for two reasons: I can't stop the movements exactly where I need. It needs to be pre-calculated since motor doesn't stop immediately. It sounds to me something like inverse kinematic. Correct me if I am wrong. The second; I can achieve 5 micrometer accuracy with steppers which I can't imagine with dc motors.

Comment: What you are describing is precisely a servomotor.  What you are missing is a good double loop control algorithm and a motion profiler. Any real CNC software would implement the latter, and it is something you would need even with steppers also. You basically trashed a theoretically decent machine and turned it into a bad one.

Comment: @All... Thank you for the comments. Regarding current control I can say that the only limit is inside my primitive design. I used BC237 and BU406 transistors in Darlington configuration. If you calculate by using minimum hfe values (in datasheets) of both transistors the driver provides around 2 Amps. But if you use maximum hfe values in calculation then driver provides more than 5 Amps! My steppers are rated as 2 Amps. All of your comments together with the other indicators I have, suggest that I over-currented the steppers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thank you for your explanation. I didn't know that. I will immediately start learning about it:)